# PHP Smarty template main page problam

Tags: php, smarty

I want to change my website main page, using php code!, I found the tpl file which I need to change, problem is that I have no experience in tpl and I want to write it with php but it won't work. I am trying to use:

```
{include_php file="/path/to/somefile.php"}
```

To use php language but it does not work. How does it work with tpl in Smarty templates using php language.

Comment: What version of Smarty are you using? As of Smarty 3.1 the {include_php} tags are only available from SmartyBC.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion the following is a php file

```
include_once("/var/www/html/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php");
$smartyobject=new Smarty();

$varr="stackoverflow"; //php variable it can also be a array";
$smartyobject->assign("website", $varr); //assigning a variable to "website", and this is now a smarty variable.
$smartyobject->display("tplfile"); //this is the actuall file that get displayed, in this tpl file you can use "website" variable {$website}
```

smarty has so many in functions loops.. so there is no need include any php file. do whatever you want to in the php file save the result in a variable and display it in a tpl file.